Ubuntu on WSL2にて、$sudo service dockerを実行したい。
環境
Windows11 23H2

Windows PowerShell> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2

ubuntu@user:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

ubuntu@user:~$ uname -a
Linux user 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@user:~$ 

やりたいこと
$sudo service dockerのコマンドをエラーなしで実行したい。
実施手順
$sudo service dockerを実行すると下記のエラーが発生する。
ubuntu@user:~$ sudo service docker start
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

下記のサイトを参考にして、dockerのプロセスとコンテナを強制終了する。
https://zenn.dev/shirokumakun/articles/3ba7c1e172dc39
ubuntu@user:~$ ps axf | grep docker | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sudo sh 
ubuntu@user:~$ 

$ sudo service docker startを実行すると、エラーが出る。
ubuntu@user:~$ sudo service docker start
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.       

$ sudo dockerdを実行すると、エラーが出る。
ubuntu@user:~$ sudo dockerd
INFO[2024-10-25T12:02:47.868821199+09:00] Starting up                                  
failed to load listeners: can't create unix socket /mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock: listen unix /mnt/wsl/shared-docker/docker.sock: bind: no such file or directory

エラー文詳細
systemctl status docker.serviceを実行すると下記のエラーがでる。
ubuntu@user:~$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-10-25 13:31:03 JST; 2min 30s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 52603 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited>
   Main PID: 52603 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 25 13:31:03 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Oct 25 13:31:03 user systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 25 13:31:03 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 25 13:31:03 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 13:31:03 user systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
lines 1-18/18 (END)

journalctl -xeを実行すると、下記のエラーが発生する。
ubuntu@user:~$ journalctl -xe
-- The job identifier is 4386.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 4386.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 4383 and the job result is failed.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit docker.socket has entered the 'failed' state with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Oct 25 13:31:25 user sudo[52843]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Oct 25 13:31:31 user sudo[52951]:   ubuntu : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/do>
Oct 25 13:31:31 user sudo[52951]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 25 13:31:31 user sudo[52951]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
lines 4532-4565/4565 (END)

ubuntu@user:~$ dockerd
INFO[2024-10-25T14:10:39.228983131+09:00] Starting up                                  
dockerd needs to be started with root privileges. To run dockerd in rootless mode as an unprivileged user, see https://docs.docker.com/go/rootless/
ubuntu@user:~$ 

どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

エラーメッセージに書いてあるようにSee "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.してみてはどうでしょう？ それから少し古い記事ですがWSL2はデフォルトではsystemdが有効になっていないというのがあるようですが。WSL2のUbuntuにSSHで接続する方法【systemd対応版】, WSL での詳細設定の構成, systemd を使用して WSL で Linux サービスを管理する

ありがとうございます。
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.を実行しましたが、よくわかりませんでした。

こんな記事があるようなので、新しいOSイメージを使って確認してみてはどうでしょう？ WSL2 (Ubuntu-20.04)にDockerをインストール あるいは他にこんな記事とか。WSL2 + Ubuntu 20.04 + Docker 環境構築手順, Dockerのインストール手順【WSL2】【Ubuntu 20.04 LTS】, WSL2のubuntu20.04にdockerのLINUX版をインストールする（Docker for Windowsは使わない）

@taka メッセージ内容は systemctl status docker.service や journalctl -xe を実行し内容を確認 (journalctl 側のコマンドは詳細情報がでる) ということ

確認ですが、/etc/wsl.conf でLinux起動時にsystemdが動くように設定をしているでしょうか? 設定のやり方は、 https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/wsl-config で確認できます。
